# Yeoman generator-backbone app in test

Tags: backbone.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

After installing yeoman and backbone-generator, I generate my project with "yo backbone" but it generates some of the app in the folder test and grunt serve doesn't work.

I reinstalled several times yeoman & generator-backbone but nothing works.

Someone would have the solution to this problem ?

Comment: Which OS? Node version? npm version?

Comment: OS X 10.9.5
npm : 1.4.3
and node v0.10.26

Thanks for the answer

Comment: Are you sure you are using latest backbone generator v0.3.3?

Comment: Yes, I uninstalled node and all my npm packages then reinstalled all but nothing changes.

Comment: I think there is something wrong in the path of the generator because the files create are only those that do not begin with "../app" : create ../bower.json, create ../.jshintrc, create ../.editorconfig, [create in test folder] create Gruntfile.js, [create in test folder] create package.json, [create in test folder] create app/styles/main.scss, create ../app/404.html, create ../app/favicon.ico, create ../app/robots.txt, [create in test folder] create app/index.html, [create in test folder] create app/scripts/main.js

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure you create a folder for you app, then cd into it and run the generator. You should have your app up and running, for example myApp

```
// first create your new app folder, then cd into it
mkdir myApp
cd myApp
// scaffold your backbone app 
npm install -g generator-backbone
yo backbone
```

That should be all you need

Comment: I already tested this and it doesn't work. I have always app in test